# ubuntu software or gnome software not loading in ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: software-center, gnome-software

suddenly gnome-software stop working as I cancelled installing an application, after that it won't load anymore.

Answer (score 0):

go to system monitor and look for gnome-software under processes tab, click on gnome-software and end task then, restart gnome-software.